# Kotlin Spring: Unresolved reference => copy

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and Spring and was developing mini project for learning experience.
This function is for updating todo's which are already created/added and find it by Id and update the data. But I get `Unresolved Reference: copy`, and no documentation found.

```
fun putTodo(id: Long, newTodo: Todo): ResponseEntity<Todo> =
  todoRepository.findById(id).map { currentTodo ->
    val updatedTodo: Todo = 
      currentTodo.copy(
        title = newTodo.title,
        status = newTodo.status
      )
    ResponseEntity.ok().body(todoRepository.save(updatedTodo))
  }.orElse(ReponseEntity.notFound().build())
```

Answer (score 9):

In order for `copy()` to exist, `Todo` must be `data class`.